# Cosmos Document query to locate latest record per type

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a collection where I am storing the `timestamp` and its latest `location` with the following class:

```
public class TrackingInfo 
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("_partition_key")]
    public string _PartitionKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("asset_id")]
    public string AssetId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("unix_timestamp")]
    public double UnixTimestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("location")]
    public Point Location { get; set; }
}
```

which is partitioned by `_PartitionKey` which contains a construct like this:

`tracking._PartitionKey = $"tracking_{tracking.AssetId.ToLower()}_{DateTime.Today.ToString("D")}";`

Looks like there is no way to do a `Group by` on  the collection.

Can someone please help me create a SQL document query to find the latest entry for each `AssetId` and its `Location` and `Timnestamp` when the data was recorded.

**Update 1:**

what if I change the `_PartitionKey` to represent per day something like below:

`tracking._PartitionKey = $"tracking_{DateTime.Today.ToString("D")}";`

would it make it easier to get all assets and its latest tracking record?

Comment: Do you know your `AssetId` values? Overall, with that partition key you will have issues to get a performant query in this scenario. You will essentially need to look at the `TOP xxx` values ordered by the latest `_ts` or `timestamp` for each of your AssetIds - across all your partitions. You would probably be better off redesigning your partition structure or storing this data seperately, e.g. by using the change feed to collect the updates and keeping the latest state somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @AlexAIT ! Actually this is exactly the challenge I am facing today.  I want to basically query for all the Assest's that re in less than `1Km` distance from a point and send them a notification. I was told its not a good idea to store the current location of `Asset` with `Asset Metadata` and also insert its location event in another document as then the RU utilized will be more, its easier to insert in this collection and query the data from the collection when required. Any idea how can I work around this issue.

Comment: You would store the "last location" separately (different document) from your "location changes" - otherwise you would not know if your "within 1km" search is even the last location of an asset - it might have moved outside the range. If you have that, you can just search by your "1km point" and you will only find the right items, because you only save the "last" location. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/geospatial
Your partition key could also be only the assetId depending on how many assets you have. It is not required that every document has a unique partition key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, my suggestion would be to solve your problem differently.

Assumption: You have a large number of assetIds and don't know the values beforehand:

- Have one document that represents the latest state of your asset
- Have another document that represents the location events of your asset
- Update the first document whenever there is a new location event
- You can put both types of documents in the same collection or separate them - both approaches have benefits. I would probably separate them.

Then do a query "what assets are within 1km of xxx" ([Querying spatial types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/geospatial))

Sidenote: It might be a good idea to use the assetId as partitionKey instead of your combined key. Using such a key is very bad for queries

If you only have very few assetIds, you can use those to only find the latest updates by using and ordering by the timestamp field. This will only return the last item

Comment: Wouldn't this approach increase my cost of DB operation `RU cost` inserting the tracking information is just `4 RU` , but updating the document in as you suggest costs additional `13 RU`. So each event now will cost me total of `17 RU`. instead of 4. is this still worth it?.

Comment: Queries aren't free either. Queries with your current data structure could easily cost hundreds `RUs` **per query**. It really depends on the volume of your data and queries. If writing is the concern, you can always delay your writes to to the main document so it costs less. You can also put your event data into a cheaper storage, e.g. table storage, if you don't have many query scenarios left for it.

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB doesn't support `group by` feature,you could vote up [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/18561901-add-group-by-support-for-aggregate-functions).

Provide a third-party package [[documentdb-lumenize](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize) for your reference which supports group by feature,it has `.net` example:

```
string configString = @"{
    cubeConfig: {
        groupBy: 'state', 
        field: 'points', 
        f: 'sum'
    }, 
    filterQuery: 'SELECT * FROM c'
}";
Object config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(configString);
dynamic result = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<dynamic>("dbs/db1/colls/coll1/sprocs/cube", config);
Console.WriteLine(result.Response);
```

You could group by `assetId` column and get the max `timestamp`.

Comment: Thanks!, I am actually looking to find the latest Tracking record for all the assets in my collection. is there an easier way to achieve this?